# PIG LOAD not responding

Tags: apache-pig

I'm new to PIG and I wanted to run some test, I made a simple test file and try to load it, but it isn't responding.

```
bin/pig -x local
grunt>;
grunt> A = LOAD 'test/test' USING PigStorage() As (lines:chararray)
>>
>>
```

At this stage I can't do anything, I suppose PIG is still trying  to load my file.
My file is a simple 4 lines text file so it shouldn't be long to load.
I managed to load that file yesterday so I know it is possible to load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot ";" to end the line.

By the way, Pig won't load your file, or do anything until you ask him to dump or store your data. Doing this, it can optimize the workflow.